# ScrollView не работает.Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview, scrollview

Не работает скролинг,хотя я до этого и по-другому делала. Я и делала скролл родителем, а linearlayout делала потомком, но все равно ничего не выходит.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".ActivityThree">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/slideViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: у вас скорее всего касание пэйджером перехватывается, проверьте

Answer (score 0):

Вот ваш код, изменил пару параметров:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2400dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/slideViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

PS: 2400dp замените на wrap_content, когда убедитесь что все хорошо. Scroll не будет работать когда контенту достаточно места.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам)Все работает)